# Implement in-app subscription for multi devices?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription

I'm making an Android application that will include a subscription using in-app billing from Google (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html).

The aim is to let user to have 1 subscription per device.
I know that Google limit subscription for 1 google mail account but not for 1 device, that's why I made my own restriction using a server with a database.

So I made a pool of 10 subscriptions in the developer console product list and I want that when a device subscribe for the 1st subscription, a second device (using the same google account) will subscribe for the next subscription...

But when I want the second device chose automatically the next subscription not even bought on the account, it is saying to me "Product already own". The problem is that the current inventory is not refreshed.

I'm using IabHelper and here is the part of code where I'm trying to buy the next subscription available.

```
public void initIab() throws IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {
        iabHelper = new IabHelper(this, AppConfig.APPLICATION_KEY);

        iabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) throws IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(iabInventoryListener());
                    billingServiceReady = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

private IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener iabInventoryListener() {
        return new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

                if (iabHelper == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }

                String[] PREMIUM_KEYS = {"premium1","premium2","premium3","premium4","premium5","premium6","premium7","premium8","premium9","premium10"};

                Purchase premiumPurchase = null;
                String premiumKey;
                boolean payload = false;
                for(String key : PREMIUM_KEYS) {
                    if (inventory.hasPurchase(key)) {
                        premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(key);
                        premiumKey = key;
                        payload = verifyDeveloperPayload(hasPurchase,premiumKey);
                        if(payload)
                            break;
                    }
                }

                session.setPremium(achatPremium != null && payload);

            }

        };
    }
```

Please could you help me to find a solution ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thank you.